# Setting ListView width param has no effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

The line below with the comment "no effect" has ... no effect, i.e. the width is not set to 200. The ListView fills the entire width of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_alphabet_layout);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

ListView listView = new ListView(this);
// the following line as no effect
listView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

// side index
LinearLayout sideIndexLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
sideIndexLinearLayout.setId(R.id.sideIndex);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams sideIndexLinearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, // width
                                                                                                                                                                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); // height
sideIndexLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(sideIndexLinearLayoutParams);
sideIndexLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
sideIndexLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// add now so that sideIndexLinearLayout is a child of the RelativeLayout.
// This will enable us to get the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to addRule()
relativeLayout.addView(listView);
relativeLayout.addView(sideIndexLinearLayout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams listViewParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)listView.getLayoutParams();
listViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
listView.setLayoutParams(listViewParams); //causes layout update

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sideIndexParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)sideIndexLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
sideIndexParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
sideIndexLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(sideIndexParams); //causes layout update
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/list_alphabet_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

Try to set

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

instead

Layout parameters depends on the container element. In this case your ListView is inside a RelativeLayout so you need RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this makes no difference. I tried moving that to after the ListView had been added to the RelativeLayout, but this made no difference, either.

Comment: so maybe ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT returns 0 ?

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is correct as far as it goes. Later in the code, there is an Adapter which is messing with the row layout and I think this is where I need to change the code.